# When does a stochastic process have finite second moment?

Tags: stochastic-processes

For a known probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ where $\Omega$ is the event space, $\mathcal{F}$ a $\sigma$-algebra and $P$ is the (known) probability measure, let $f(x(t,\xi),\xi), \,\, \xi \in \Omega$ b be general nonlinear function,
\begin{equation}
\dot{x}(t,\xi) = f(x(t,\xi),\xi).
\end{equation}
What needs to hold for $f$ and/or $\xi$ such that $f(x(t,\xi),\xi) \in L^2$, i.e.
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[|x(t,\xi)-\mathbb{E}[x(t,\xi)]|^2]<\infty.
\end{equation}
If this is too broad of a question - what if $f$ is a polynomial?